# Set TextFromField style in Theme

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So in my flutter app, I create TextFormField to use as an input like so (and return it in a scaffold):

```
final password = TextFormField(
      controller: passController,
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
);
```

I would like to change the `style` property inside a `themeData`, but I couldn't find which property to specify.

The closest one I could get to was `textTheme: new TextTheme(body1: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange))`, but this one does nothing to my TextFormField.

How can I set the TextFormField style? Please help, I'm really new to Dart and also programming. I'm currently 13 and I have nobody to help me out with these types of things.

P.S: The complete code is on GitHub if needed: https://github.com/Legolaszstudio/novynotifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uhm! That's a long question. `TextFormField` are subclass of the `TextField`. The default style of `TextField` could be found from source below.

```
final TextStyle style = themeData.textTheme.subhead.merge(widget.style);
```

So, you have 2 solutions for your source code.

### Solution 1

- Delete `style` property are inputted to `password`.

```
final password = TextFormField(
  controller: passController,
  autofocus: false,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.orange), // ★ => Delete this.
);
```

- Define a custom `subhead` style from `DataTheme` and input into Material app.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      subhead: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
    ),
  ),
  home: null,
)
```

### Solution 2

- Define a custom `subhead` style from `DataTheme` and input into Material app.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      subhead: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
    ),
  ),
  home: null,
)
```

- Copy this subhead style into `password`

```
final themes = Theme.of(context);
final password = TextFormField(
  controller: passController,
  autofocus: false,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
  style: themes.textTheme.subhead, // ★ => Update this.
);
```

Comment: subhead is now deprecated, use subtitle2 ;)

Comment: subtitle1, not 2 :)

Answer (score 11):

Update:

If you want to change the Text within TextField by Theme of your Flutter App. It's now subtitle1 of TextTheme.

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
    subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
)
```

Comment: It's weird that Flutter allows all the other text styles to be set on the theme, like label style, but not the input style itself.

Comment: This worked. Unfortunately, `subTitle1` cannot be used on Material Design 3. Instead use  `titleMedium`.

Comment: @Scott Yup... Who would want their TextField text to be the same size as their titles? A goddamn psychopath.

Answer (score 5):

## 2021 - 2022

The [Material spec for typography](https://m3.material.io/styles/typography/type-scale-tokens) changed significantly in 2021 and now uses display, headline, title, body, and label types. titleMedium is the one that will effect all of your TextFields and TextFormFields.

This fact is highlighted in the [TextTheme class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html) docs as well.

If you're using the the titleMedium TextStyle for something else, you can easily wrap your TextFields and TextFormFields in a Theme widget and update this style specifically for these widgets like this:

```dart
Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                  titleMedium: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12, 
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  ),
                )),
        child: TextField()
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `subhead`

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
    subhead: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
)
```